# How to match the line which does not contain backslash (\) when there is it on the preceding lines?

Tags: regex, parsing

How to match the line which does not contain backslash (\) when there is it on the preceding lines?

I am creating an accurate Notepad++ syntax highlight for Sublime Text 3, now I need to match the line which end the macro definition after the backslashes (\) break line. To get it working, I need to match (choose, create a regex) to know where/what will be the last line.

This picture is how it should be:
[image: goal]

This is how I am getting with:

    `\\\n.*(?!\\\n)`

[image: present]

## Here is the regex

Here is the https://regex101.com/r/nQ1bP0/1 where you can play with it until get it done. 
[image: done]

Get it done is to make it match the last line:

    `&& get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) )`

not the second one:

    `( get_realplayersnum() < get_pcvar_num( cvar_voteMinPlayers ) \`

```
#define IS_NOMINATION_MININUM_PLAYERS_CONTROL_ENABLED() \
    ( get_realplayersnum() < get_pcvar_num( cvar_voteMinPlayers ) \
      && get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) \
      && get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) \
      && get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) )

stock hi()
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working --

`((?:.*\\\n)+.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/qT4vX6/1

Comment: Sorry, it is matching everything from the first file line, not just the last macro line. Then I updated the example to this http://regexr.com/3e0s6, If you put your regex on this new one, you will see it.

Comment: Just updated the regex. Works with the new test input.

Comment: Thanks, it really capturing everything now. However, looks like a sublime problem now, it is not highlighting anything on Sublime Text. https://regex101.com/r/nQ1bP0/4, it is taking 10000 steps to solve it, may be should be it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qT4vX6/1 -- 409 steps  (will match lines with just a slash. Hope thats acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

This solves the question https://regex101.com/r/nQ1bP0/3:

`(?<=\\\n).*[^\\]\n`

But does not solve the highlight problem on Sublime because it does not support Lookaround and stills necessary to treat the cases where the macro does not use backslashes (\).

```
/**
 * Change this value from 0 to 1, to use the Whitelist feature as a Blacklist feature.
 */
#define IS_TO_USE_BLACKLIST_INSTEAD_OF_WHITELIST 0

    }
}

/**
 * How to match the line which does not contain slash (/) when there is it on the preceding lines?
 */
#define IS_NOMINATION_MININUM_PLAYERS_CONTROL_ENABLED() \
    ( get_realplayersnum() < get_pcvar_num( cvar_voteMinPlayers ) \
      && get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) \
      && get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) \
      && get_pcvar_num( cvar_nomMinPlayersControl ) )    // <-- is matching this whole line only
not match this
stock hi()
{
```

## Edit

This completely solves the problem:

`((.*\\\n)*.*[^\\]\n)|\n`

Now sublime text is recognizing correctly the line breaks. It only works on sublime text, because it needs to match the end of the highlighting, as the highlighting start is catch by another regular expression:

    `(?x)
    ^\s*\#\s*(define)\s+             # define
    ((?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))     # macro name
    (?:                              # and optionally:
        (\()                         # an open parenthesis
            (
                \s* [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* \s*           # first argument
                (?:(,) \s* [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* \s*)*  # additional arguments
                (?:\.\.\.)?          # varargs ellipsis?
            )
        (\))                         # a close parenthesis
    )?`